# VIM swap-file best practices?

Tags: swap-file

Everytime I cut out of a session in vim by losing my connection I'm rather filled with dred  (and yet I continue to use vim...what a masochistist I must be) because when I open my files again a pile of swap-files are waiting to take a shot at destroying my work.  What are the best practices for working with vim swap files?  Do you just pick the newest one?  If the file works the way you expect, do you just delete the swap files?  How do you get rid of them?

Comment: Swap files are there to protect your work.  Consider using gnu screen.

Comment: I agree with Dr Eval, that swap files are actually there to protect you and not the other way around. But if you dislike them, you can always turn them off with `set noswapfile`.

Comment: I don't want to turn the functionality off; it's annoying but as you state useful.

Comment: I just want to know how to properly use it.

Comment: @DrEval I use tmux

Comment: If you use tmux, you shouldn't need to worry about losing your connection: just reattach to your session when you reconnect. You might also be interested in [mosh](https://mosh.org/) and in @ChristianBrabandt's [Recover plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/Recover.vim/).

Comment: In that case your swap files are the consequence of you not reattaching to the same tmux session.

Comment: For years I didn't bother to use `tmux` because I thought "I'm local, I don't need it", and I also thought I was getting slightly better features with GUI vim. When I finally did the (short) `tmux` learning curve I wished I started years before. Tmux has two main features - a) persistence during disconnection b) panes and windows (which also persist). Tmux combined with Vim is the world's best IDE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### Don't Panic!

Recovering files is *always* safe, because vim *never* writes any changes until you write them yourself. So recovering from a swap file and then closing without saving won't change anything.

#### Organize your swapfiles:

Get vim to put all your swap files in the same place, so you always know where they are:

```
set directory^=$HOME/.vim/swap//
```

or wherever you prefer. Use `//` at the end of the filename makes vim use absolute file paths for the swap file names so you don't get name collisions. **Make sure the directory exists, or vim won't use it** (it won't create it for you).

Note: This only works on environment variables, if you want to use a vimscript variable then we need to use some `:execute` magic:

```
execute "set directory^=".my_vim_home_var."/swap//"
```

#### Diff the differences:

Vim's help suggests a very useful command to use in this situation: `:DiffOrig`.  It's **not a default vim command**, so copy the implementation from `:h :DiffOrig` into your vimrc. (it's also in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` if you have vim8). Now, you can recover the file and simply run DiffOrig to get a vimdiff of what's changed from the unmodified version.

If you want to compare the contents of multiple swap files, recover your file with each different swap file, and then write the result to temporary files. Now load up the files and run `:diffthis` on each file, make the changes you want, write back to the original file, and delete the temporary and swap files.

#### Useful commands:

`:swapname` : get the name vim is using for the swap file for the current buffer (`:h :swapname`)
`:recover` : recovers the selected file, same as when you start vim and press <kbd>R</kbd> (`:h :recover`)

#### Check out the help:

Vim has an entire section of the user manual on recovery: `:usr_11.txt`
Vim's reference help on swap files: `:h swap-file` , `h recovery`
Help on the directory option (for setting the swap file location): `:h 'directory'`

**Edit:** Modified example for setting directory, as pointed out in comments by @B Layer

Comment: What about when you end up with multiple swap files?  Because of many many dropped connections?

Comment: I mentioned that in the second paragraph of "Diff the Differencces". Once you've used diffs to determine which changes you want to keep delete all the temporary files and old swap files you made (now you know where all the swap files are).

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `exec`...`set directory^=$HOME/.vim/swap//` works fine as long as `$HOME` is an initialized environment variable. See `:h expand-env`. Also works with `dictionary`, `undodir`, and `backupdir` to name a few.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that! I use a vimscript variable in my configuration instead there, hence the execute, and forgot environment variables don't need that. Thinking of it, I should probably just use vim to set an environment variable instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the `//` at the end of the swap file directory avoids collisions. I've been using Vim for years and was never aware of this, and was just wondering "how does Vim avoid collisions?".

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I have turned off swap and backup files, as it tends to create swap
files and backup files everywhere and frequently creates conflicts. Vim's
persistent-undo has been much more reliable and error-free.

Vim currently has persistent undo, its a much more fine grained method of
backup.  Every time, you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the current state of the file is
captured.

You can use `:undolist`, or plugins like [gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim),
or [undo-tree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) to browse your undo history.

To use vim this way:

- create a directory where you editing history for each file will be captured
- tell vim to use that directory
- enable persistent undo

In the shell:

```
mkdir ~/.vim/undodir
```

In Vim

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
```

To turn off swap files: `:set noswapfile`

Comment: There are a couple of pretty big problems with this answer. 1. Persistent undo solves a different problem to swap files (and `'writebackup'` addresses yet another problem). Having persistent undo enabled won't help if your computer crashes. You *can* argue that swap files are unnecessary for other reasons (modern OS stability, the existence of UPSes), but you haven't done so in this answer. 2. setting `'undodir'` *doesn't* enable persistent undo! You need to set `'undofile'` for this