# How can I view the name of the swapfile being used for the current buffer?

Tags: buffers, swap-file

Let's say I recovered a bunch of swapfiles in quick succession:

```
gvim -r .swv
gvim -r .swu
gvim -r .swt
```

And then cycled through them all a few times before finding that one of them was nonsense. I want to now know which swap file is represented by this buffer of useless contents, so that I may delete it so as not to have known garbage floating around on my hard drive. How can I switch to that buffer/window and then query the name of the swapfile associated with that particular buffer?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:swapname
```

This will show the filename of the swapfile for the current buffer. (For example: `/c/path/.swu`)

I found this (after a few tries) by typeing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>.

I also found this question: [VIM swap-file best practices?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16037/vim-swap-file-best-practices/#16047), which includes some other interesting and useful commands.

Comment: Excellent that you shared how you found it, too.