# What does 'set setting^=value' really mean?

Tags: vimrc, set

There is an [old question here about best practices to store swap files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16037/205), and there is [an answer by flemingfleming](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16047/205) (who haven't visited the site since 2018) where he suggested the following:

```
set directory^=$HOME/.vim/swap//
```

For what reason is the `^` character is used there?

Yes, I know I can open `:h set`, but I simply don't understand.

> ```
> :se[t] {option}^={value}              *:set^=*
>           Multiply the {value} to a number option, or prepend
>           the {value} to a string option.  When the option is a
>           comma-separated list, a comma is added, unless the
>           value was empty.
>           Also see |:set-args| above.
> ```

Comment: The end of the first sentence and middle sentence: `'directory'` is a comma-separated list.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I still don't understand how is it related here.

Comment: “prepend” means add to/before the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As help states:

> or prepend the `{value}` to a string option.

Option `directory` is a string, so if you have `set directory=path1,path2` and then do `set directory^=path0`, result `directory` would be `path0,path1,path2`.